# Image of MasterPage not found on (sub-folder)

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a button with with image and this button is called on the MasterPage.master, until here everything OK. But I have a sub-folder (child folder). So this image not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link the url of the image through to the subfolder

```
<img src="/FolderName/ImageName.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks Dude, I have this... <a src="../Folder[...]"/> I took the two points and run!!! Thanks!